# Sony Xperia Z1 - problems with voice sound after update to Android 5.0.2

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, calls, sony-xperia-z

After update Android to 5.0.2 there is a problem in my Sony Xperia Z1 compact. When I make or receive phone calls the caller does not hear me (or hears, but poorly, with noise).
After restart these problems disappears for some time, but later appears againg.
Are there any known workaround for such issues?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the workaround - to turn off the noise suppression. It fixed the problem for me.

To do that, press `Settings -> Call -> Microphone noise suppression (off)`

Answer (score 0):

I have read the article about Sony patch, hopefully it is coming. Meanwhile, I press audio output selection button on the screen twice, that fixes the issue for the call I receive and have audio issue as described above.